# List - display sublist item vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sorry for the poor question wording, I am struggling to find the correct way to ask this.

I have a list in this codepen https://codepen.io/meek/pen/BmYZQB

```html
<ul class="cageList">
  <li class="listHeader">
    <span class="header">Title</span>
    <span class="itemNo">Sub&nbsp;<span>2</span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Item 2 type small</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Item 2 type big</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Item 3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with some styling done. Item 2 type small and big are supposed to be in a "item 2" sublist, that is styled like this:

[image]

But I am struggling to come up with a good way to list item 2 vertically as in the picture without throwing everything out of whack. I've tried to make a simple flexbox div with column on the right/rows on the left but that seems to mess up the alternating colours with :nth-child(even). Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex can help you out with this, no list needed.

```css
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    .col {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 1em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

   .white-bg { background-color: #fff; }
   .grey-bg { background-color: #ccc; }
   .dark-grey-bg { background-color: #aaa; }

    .col-2 {
      flex: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .container {
      width: 300px;
    }

    .rotate {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col grey-bg">Item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col dark-grey-bg">
    <div class="rotate">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        Small
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 grey-bg">
        Big
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Item 3</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This almost answers it, but how can I get the alternating colouring on the items like this? Using nth-child(even) I get this https://codepen.io/meek/pen/BmYZQB

Comment: I have updated the above snippet for my preferred method. Some may think this sloppy the code a little, but this is what I like to do. I just like to create a color class then add the class to the needed div that needs the bg-color.

Comment: sadly this solution doesn't work for me, as I don't know how many elements are going to be in the list before it's generated. In the end I placed the group element using absolute positioning and stuck to the nth-child method, but since your method is overall nicer I'll mark it as answer. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well glad you figured it out. Would be nice if you could post the code you used for future people that stumble across this